# Como Anadir nombres y texto a botones dinámicamente a un table-panel? c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Hola chicos tengo una pregunta resulta que por medio de una consulta necesito generar botones en un tablepanel
Puedo Generar los botones pero no puedo ingresarles un nombre y un texto
como podria recorrer los botones del tablepanel y asignarles un nombre y texto
El nombre y texto deberan ser los mismos datos de la consulta

Aqui esta mi CODIGO

```
 for (int f = 0; f < filan; f++)
         {
            
                for (int c = 0; c < 5; c++)
                {
                
                    tpanelmenu.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 100F));
                    tpanelmenu.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 100F));
               
                Button boton = new Button();
                boton.BackColor = Color.White;
                    boton.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
              

                    tpanelmenu.Controls.Add(boton, c, f);
                    if (f == 0)
                    {
                        tpanelmenu.ColumnCount += 1;
                    }
                }
           
                tpanelmenu.RowCount += 1;
         }

            tpanelmenu.ColumnCount -= 1;
            tpanelmenu.RowCount -= 1;
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! porque no pudiste? que problema tuviste? Porque ahi por ejemplo le estas asignando un color al boton.. con lo cual, ponerle un nombre es usar la propiedad que corresponde, y el contenido tambien es lo mismo...

Comment: Hola amigo, Puedes indicar como asignas filan?¿Quizas las filas totales de un datatable o una lista o un Arreglo?